# Mysql Order By after Group By causes very slow query

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I can't figure out why the 'order by' clauses in Query2 below causes it to take over a minute while the first one returns results instantly. Is there a better way to do this 'order by'

Fast:

```
select c.id, max(date(a.sent)) as sent,
    if(c.id in (select id from bin where (num=1 or  num=2)),1,0) as done
from test c, test2 a
where c.id=a.id
group by c.id
limit 1;
```

Slow

```
select c.id, max(date(a.sent)) as sent,
    if(c.id in (select id from bin where (num=1 or num=2)),1,0) as done
from test c, test2 a
where c.id=a.id
group by c.id
order by done, sent
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because the "columns" in the order by clause are not real columns, but aliases for calculations elsewhere in the query.  Thus, they aren't indexed, and the server has to order them on the fly.  Using a join for the calculation of done, rather than a subquery, would likely speed this up a lot.

Comment: With most modern RDBMS, sub-queries are not really worse than Joins. That was only true of older RDBMS that could not figure out when the two were equivalent. Today, sometimes a sub-query is a better way to go... it all depends.

Answer (score 0):

If you were bringing back all records, the sorting should not take much time, even though they are  computed / non-indexed fields. However, you are using "Limit 1". This changes the approach of the optimizer.

In the first case, you are ordering by an ID. Since you have "limit 1" and the ID probably has an index, the optimizer can go ID by ID and when it gets one records that matches the WHERE clause it can return.

However, in the second query, even though you only want 1 record, the optimizer does not know which one that will be unless it computes the entire set (as if you did not have "limit 1") and then returns only the first one.

Take off the "LIMIT 1" and compare the two queries. If the difference remains, it may be a different problem.

It is difficult to say what would work best with your volumes. Try this query:

```
select id, max(date(sent)) as sent, 0 As done
from test2
where exists (select 1 from bin where bin.id=test2.id and num not in (1,2))
group by id
union all
select id, max(date(sent)) as sent, 1 As done
from test2
where exists (select 1 from bin where bin.id=test2.id and num in (1,2))
group by id
order by done, sent
limit 1
```

[SQL Fiddle is here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b158/12) if you want to tweak it.

I left out the test table, because you were not bringing back any field except ID, which is already on test2. If you need other fields from test, you will have to tweak it.

Comment: You are correct. I just ran both queries without the Limit 1 and the 'fast' version actually ran slower than the 'fast' one. So clearly, 'limit 1' is having an impact. Yes, I really do only want to return one record back. What's a better way to do this?

Comment: Thanks. Definitely faster but still not usable fast. I do need data from 'test' table I just didn't include it in the example. One table has about 300k records and the other one about 2 million.

Comment: Ok, how many records in each of those three tables: test, test2, bin?

Comment: Also, the only filter is bin.num. Of the records in bin, roughly what proportion would have num=1 or 2?  And, is there an index on bin that has ID as the first field and NUM as the second? In test2, is there an index with ID as the first field and SENT as the second?
Finally, is creating new indexes a possible answer in your context?

Comment: Thanks. I've decided to modify our DB structure a bit to make this work, seems like I need to jump through too many hoops for the query to be efficient